# Importxml on attribute

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to scrape the following content attributes from [this site](https://www.masterofmalt.com/whiskies/arran-robert-burns-blended-scotch-whisky/) using a googlesheet. Unfortunately every variation i can think of seems to fail

```
<span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue" content="3.5"></span>
        <span itemprop="ratingCount" content="12"></span>
        <span itemprop="reviewCount" content="12"></span>
    </span>
```

I'm looking to extract the values 3.5, 12 & 12 using

```
=importxml(A2,//*[@id='topOnProduct']/div[2]/span/span[1])
=importxml(A2,//*[@id='topOnProduct']/div[2]/span/span[1]@content)
=importxml(A2,"//span[@itemprop='ratingValue']/@content")
```

and about 50 other variations on the respective attributes - i'm also having no joy using kiimono. Can anyone advise me where i'm going wrong/show me how to achieve this

Comment: How should anyone know where you are going wrong if you do not show what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks, but please do not post essential information in comments - edit your question instead. Now, _what exactly_ would you like to select? I.e. what exactly should appear in the cell you've typed the formula into? Please show that, too.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem in Kimono if i assign the values correctly it wont save the API. Any idea where i'm going wrong?